# iOS cookies are not being sent back

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, httpcookie

Having a very hard time with cookies on iOS. This issue has plagued me for a month now. I have a problem where my cookies are not being returned by Safari on iOS. Other browsers are not a problem.

Unfortunately, in my testing, I haven't been able to reproduce this issue. I have a physical iPhone myself, and can't get the issue to manifest.

What's happening is users are reporting issues where they can't login. My server code has been logging incoming requests, and in the instances where people can't login, the cookies are absent.

I'm wondering if ITP is getting in the way, but as far as I can tell, I've done everything right to satisfy it.

Here's a screenshot of the debug tools. It shows my two cookies ('cvt' and 'h'), with the expected expiration date.

[image]

Couple of things I should note. This is for a site hosted on azurewebsites.net, so it's a subdomain cookie being set. Cookies are set to be httponly, secure, and SameSite=strict